# counting of distinct values in R

Tags: r, count

I have a list of data as part of big data frame, it is sorted by time so I can not change the order of the list :

```
ID <-  c("p","fxman27","duncane" ,"duncane" ,"dday1026" ,"duncane","dday1026","dday1026" ,"dday1026" ,"dday1026","cesandjoel","pali777","ranger_2","marymom6" , "deaglekl")
```

Now I need a function to produce this counts of those IDs:

```
 s<-c(1 , 2  ,3 , 3 , 4,  4  ,4 , 4 , 4  ,4 , 5,  6,  7,  8 , 9)
```

as you can see, the function count number of distinct ID's and remain constant if the ID is the same in previous row.
I don't want to use "for" loops, and prefer BASE functions.

the "s" is not simple frequency table, for that I know I can use aggregate. 
This is not a grouping question, but number of "current Id's" is auctions
Thanks

Comment: use  the `count` function from the `plyr` package. `plyr::count(ID)`

Comment: Try `match(ID, unique(ID))`

Comment: @JakeConway That won't give the desired output

Comment: count just gives me frequency. I already have the frequency, I need the "s" vector as changes if "ID" changes and remains constant as "ID" doesn't change!

Comment: @DavidArenburg 
this is close but bot I want. I need s(6)=4, but your solution will give s(6)=3.

Comment: Why would it be 4? That doesn't make any sense

Comment: because, these are bidder ID's of an auction. I am trying to look at "current number of bidders" .

Comment: @DavidArenburg:
this is not a duplicated question!

Comment: Ok, I reopened but I have no idea what the question is about. So good luck with that.

Comment: The question is actually duplicated. `cumsum(!duplicated(ID))` (the answer of @DavidArenburg from the link he provided) can reproduce your result, but `match(ID,unique(ID))` cannot because `match` function does not check duplicates of elements with smaller subscripts.

Comment: If I hadn't seen the `duplicated` answer, I'd probably do `library(tidyverse); data_frame(ID) %>% mutate(s = map_int(accumulate(ID, c), n_distinct))`. Translated to base, something like `s <- sapply(Reduce(c, ID, accumulate = TRUE), function(x){length(unique(x))})`, though I'd probably still chuck everything in a data.frame to keep relationships clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data set is large, you may be better off using dplyr, but this solves the example with base only functions:

```
apply(as.matrix(1:length(ID)), 1, function(n) length(unique(ID[1:n])))
```

Comment: This is a loop. Also, how dplyr is related here? Finally, why converting a vector to a matrix and not just use `sapply` over it?

Comment: I was thinking of using `dplyr::n_distinct`. You're right, `sapply(1:length(ID), function(n) length(unique(ID[1:n])))` would probably be best implementation of this. However, the approach by @psidom is ultimately better.

Answer (score 7):

You can count non-duplicated IDs:

```
cumsum(!duplicated(ID))
# [1] 1 2 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 6 7 8 9
```